# JSON.parse for string that contains unescaped newlines - \n

Tags: javascript, json

In python, `json.loads` takes `strict=False` param, that will parse the newline characters that have a single backslash instead of double backslashes. Like,

```
import json
a = '{"newline" : "\n"}'
json.loads(a)
```

throws error as,

```
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

But doing,

```
json.loads(a, strict=False)
```

returns,

```
{u'newline': u'\n'}
```

How can i do the same using Nodejs?

I can replace `\n` with `\\n` and then do, `JSON.parse`. But it is a tedious one to do for many other chars!!!

Comment: Why do you have this problem in the first place? The only reason I can think of is that you are generating JSON and then copy/pasting it into JavaScript source code. If you don't wrap it in quotes, and just treat it as a JavaScript literal (instead of as JSON), then the problem goes away.

Comment: Fundamentally, it seems to me the problem is with the source of the JSON, which is producing invalid JSON. If it's producing JSON that's invalid because it failed to correctly escape newlines, what *else* is it failing to do correctly that would also make the JSON invalid? Not escaping double quotes?